# Flutter keystore not creating

Tags: android, flutter, key, keytool

My Java location -

My Flutter key store is not getting created .. please

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
• Java binary at: **E:\Android Studio\jre\bin\java**
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
• Android Studio at E:\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 46.0.2
• Dart plugin version 193.7361
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

My added System variable path -
[System Variable added path Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr9aV.png)

Still, my keytool is not generating -

C:\Users\ABC\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_love_calculator.io>keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\ABC\key.jks -storety
pe JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
**'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Plzz help..

Answer (score 1):

[Yubaraj Mahata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13891538/yubaraj-mahata) Some Android licenses not accepted.
This command will help you:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer..

Click all **y** after running

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

On your desktop screen Right click **Computer**. Go to Properties > Advanced system settings (Left of the screen) > Click Environment Variables > Under System Variables, click Path > Double Click it OR Select and then click Edit > Add a semicolon at the last of your path ( if you have all the path in a single box, else leave the semicolon and click New; also if a semicolon at the end is already present then you do not require) > Add the Path of the keytool(excluding the java at the end or keytool at the end; ensure that the last term is bin ) > Click all the Oks on the pop up. BOOOOM !!! You are all set..

For the concrete path, run `flutter doctor -v` and locate the path printed after ‘Java binary at:’

##YoYo